# How to windows 7 restore if error 0x8000ffff appears? Not able to boot into system

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-restore

I have a computer with Windows 7. When I boot it, I get the usual starting animation, the harddisk LED blinks but then the screen gets black and nothing more happens. No sound, so activity, no changes when I press any keys or the mouse buttons.

When I start the computer with a Fedora 23 Linux live system from usb pendrive, it has no problems, everything works out of the box.

When I start the Windows system restore (I have testet several restore points), it takes some minutes with harddisk LED activity, but then an error appears: 0x8000ffff, and some text, that it is an unspecified error. Not helpful.

I am **not** very experienced with recent Windows systems, but very experienced with Linux and Mac OS X. So I need help here.

**Now the question is:** What is the best and fastest way to get the computer back to work with the old Windows 7 system? When I use the Windows 7 install CD, is there a way to install it over the old system? Could this work? Will the installed software work (or at least most of it)? I have not tested it, as I don’t want to destroy anything, until I know what the best approach is.

Comment: What did your research tell you? [Startup Repair: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/startup-repair-faq#1TC=windows-7): "Startup Repair is a Windows recovery tool that can fix certain system problems that might prevent Windows from starting. Startup Repair scans your computer for the problem and then tries to fix it so your computer can start correctly." and [What are the system recovery options in Windows?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7)

Comment: In your previous question I suggested you try "Startup Repair" not "System Restore". Have you tried this?

Comment: Is there a blinking cursor on the Black Screen?

Comment: Will it boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: No, it will not boot into Safe Mode. :-( And there is no blinking cursor, just black.

Answer (score 0):

The most complete answer to my newbie question seems to be this one, which unfortunately tells me, that I need to boot into my Windows 7 system (*"must be logged into Windows 7 in a administrator account to be able to do a repair install"*). Unfortunately this is not possible in my case.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Cited from the source.

**Do a Repair installation if:**

```
A System Restore did not help fix your Windows 7.
There is no other easier option left that can fix your Windows 7.
You DO NOT want to do a Clean reinstall of Windows 7.
You DO want to preserve your user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.
```

**ITEMS THAT WILL BE RESET TO DEFAULT OR AFFECTED:**

```
Sounds
Services
Visual Effects Settings
Device Drivers - Be sure to have these handy to reinstall. They do not always remain after the repair (upgrade) install.
You may lose the ability to sign on to MSN Messenger, to solve this problem have a look at this thread Unable to sign in to WLM.
You may lose your custom themes due to not having permisions set on the old themes. Go to the hidden themes folder at C:/Users/(User-Name)/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Themes, then Take Ownership of the themes folder and you will now have all your themes back.
It has been reported that you may also lose your Media Center gadget after doing the repair install.
Windows Updates will need to be checked and reinstalled again.
```

**Warnings**

```
You can only do a repair install with the same edition Windows 7 installation disc for the same edition of Windows 7 that you have installed.
You cannot use a OEM Windows 7 "Factory" Restore/Recovery type of installation disc that came with or created from a store bought computer to do a repair install with. These can only be used do a clean install instead.
You can do a repair install on a factory OEM installation with the latest official Windows 7 with SP1 ISO file here: Microsoft: Windows 7 Direct Download Links, and use Windows 7 USB-DVD Download Tool to create a bootable DVD or USB flash drive with the ISO to do the repair install from within Windows 7.
You can use a retail OEM Windows 7 installation disc to do a repair install with.
You can use a retail (full or upgrade) Windows 7 installation disc to do a repair install with.
You cannot do a repair install with a System Repair Disc. A System Repair Disc is not a installation disc, and will only boot to the System Recovery Options screen.
If you have a 32-bit (x86) Windows 7 currently installed, then you must use a 32-bit Windows 7 installation disc to be able to do a repair install with.
If you have a 64-bit (x64) Windows 7 currently installed, then you must use a 64-bit Windows 7 installation disc to be able to do a repair install with.
You can use a retail Windows 7 SP1 installation disc (ex: Technet (available), MSDN (available), or retail (when available)) to do a repair install with on a currently installed Windows 7 SP1.
You can use a Windows 7 SP1 installation disc (ex: Technet (available), MSDN (available), or retail (when available)) to do a repair install with on a currently installed slipstream Windows 7 SP1.
You cannot use a slipstream Windows 7 installation disc to do a repair install with on a currently installed Windows 7 SP1.
You cannot use a slipstream Windows 7 installation disc to do a repair install with on a currently installed slipstream Windows 7 SP1.
You can only do a repair install from within Windows 7.
You cannot do a repair install at boot or in Safe Mode.
You must be logged into Windows 7 in a administrator account to be able to do a repair install.
You must have at least 8.87 GB + what is currently being used of free space (more if you have a larger installation) on the hard drive/partition Windows 7 is installed on to do a repair install.
If you changed the default location of a user account's profile folder, then you will need to change it back to the default C:\Users location first.
If you moved the default location of a user folder, then you will need to change it back to the default C:\Users\(user-name) location first.
```

## Update

Finally I did, what was recommended in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/428525/180675) + recovered my files from the `Windows.old` directory. I had to install all the software again. But I could at least recover the configurations from the `%APPDATA%` folder.

Comment: Did you read and try the suggestions in http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7?

Comment: I’ve tried Startup Repair und System Restore. Both failed with an error window (red symbol with a cross as far as y remember). System image recovery wasn’t able, as there is no image available.